# VSCode says "Failed to run custom build command" on cbindgen, but it actually works

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, binding

I have a Rust (2021) lib. It compiled fine.

I added a build.rs file with this in it:

```
extern crate cbindgen;

use std::env;

fn main() {
    let crate_dir = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();

    cbindgen::Builder::new()
      .with_crate(crate_dir)
      .generate()
      .expect("Unable to generate bindings")
      .write_to_file("rush_engine.h");
}
```

Next, I added this to the bottom of Cargo.toml:

```
[build-dependencies]
cbindgen = "0.20.0"
```

Finally, I added a cbindgen.toml file with the contents of this:
https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen/blob/master/template.toml

If I run 'cargo build' the .h file appears as expected and there's no errors from cargo in the terminal window.

However, VS Code has the entire Cargo.toml underlined under every word with red squiggles and there's an error message at the bottom saying 'failed to run custom build command for lib_name'.

I cannot find a solution to this (have removed everything and re-added, cleaned out target folder, etc) and though it's not breaking anything, it's kinda off-putting that this glaring error keeps showing.

Any pointers on how to solve this would be grately appreciated.

Cheers

Jase

Additional requested info:

The Cargo.toml at issue looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "rush_engine"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
publish = false

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "staticlib"]

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4"

[build-dependencies]
cbindgen = "0.20.0"
```

The VSCode extensions I'm using are:

- rust-lang.rust (version 0.7.8)

...that's literally it. I don't see anything else rust related in running extensions.

Comment: Which Rust-related extension(s) are you using in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

Something Francis Gagné (thanks!) said got me wondering and experimenting. That's how I found a solution.

The solution (for me) was uninstall the official Rust extension, then install the rust-analyzer extension. This seems to have the exact same functionality, and it's not red-squiggling my entire Cargo.toml file, too!